# On blocking jaavscript in chromev73, I see blank white page instead of rendering the webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

On blocking javascript in chromev70 I see webpage displaying without any functions working as expected, while doing the same in chrome v73, i see blank white page. Could someone help me on this please. I need to go with chrome V73 as higher levels are working on v73.

Comment: What is the reason for block js from your site?

Comment: To support SEO I am blocking JavaScript